# Error message about wrong origin remote URL when running Brew Doctor

Tags: homebrew

I get this message when I run brew doctor. Did they change the url recently or do I have some other error?

```
Warning: Suspicious git origin remote found.

With a non-standard origin, Homebrew won't pull updates from
the main repository. The current git origin is:
  https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew

Unless you have compelling reasons, consider setting the
origin remote to point at the main repository, located at:
  https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew.git
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Homebrew did recently change their origin remote server URL address to https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew.git.

To make a long story short, just run `brew update` twice and you should be good to go.

See here: [Homebrew GitHub Closed Issues](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/25244)